# 0Byte session files with Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, session

We are currently facing a strange problem with PHP-Sessions.
We are running a web application on various Windows Servers with Apache/PHP installed (Apache 2.4.34 VC14 and PHP 7.1.20 VC14).

When starting Apache and using the application, everything works fine. Then after a while, on one specific server, PHP starts writing 0Byte session files and the browsers, therefore, cannot access the `sessiondata` anymore. After restarting Apache everything works fine for about 24-72h until the same problem reappears.

There is plenty of free space on the disk for storing the session files.
The `session.save_path` is correct and writeable.

Did anybody face a similar problem yet?
We couldn't find anything about that.